# Instead of VTP , what protocol can be used for non Cisco switches?

Tags: vlan, switching, proprietary

I got to know that VTP (VLAN Trunking Protocol) is a Cisco proprietary protocol.

So VTP can be used only on CISCO switches. So if there is a non-Cisco switch in a network, what kind of protocol can be used for Vlan Trunking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 802.1ak defines a protocol called **Multiple VLAN Registration Protocol** or [MVRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GARP_VLAN_Registration_Protocol#Multiple_VLAN_Registration_Protocol_.28MVRP.29) in short. Most vendors have implemented this protocol like [Juniper](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/task/configuration/mvrp-mx-series-cli.html) or [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/lanswitch/configuration/guide/lsw_cfg_mvrp.html). A cisco switch can be configured to run this protocol, although there are some [restrictions](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/lanswitch/configuration/guide/lsw_cfg_mvrp.html#wp1068279) that you have to be aware of.